# Comm command issue

Tags: comm

I'm trying to compare two gene lists and extract the common ones. I sorted my .txt files and used comm command:

comm gene_list1.txt gene_list2.txt

Strangely, when I check the output, there are many common genes that are not printed in the third line. Here is part of the output:

[image]

As you can see, AAAS and AAGAB etc. exist in both files, but they are not printed as common lines! Any idea why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: Try to avoid posting input data as images, especially when it is easy to provide it in text form.

Answer (score 0):

`$ comm file1.txt file2.txt`

The output of the above command contains three columns where the first column is separated by zero tabs and contains names **only** present in file1.txt.

The second column contains names **only** present in file2.txt and separated by one tab.

The third column contains names **common to both the files** and is separated by two tabs from the beginning of the line.

This is the **default** pattern of the output produced by comm command when no option is used.

I am assuming, both the input files are in the **sorted order**. Then the required command for your use case would be

```
$ comm -12 gene_list1.txt gene_list2.txt
```

This means both the columns (1 and 2) are suppressed (not displayed). Since you are only interested in the elements common to both the files.